# Programming environment for client side web development

Tags: javascript, css, ide, html, websocket

I have lost somehow connection to the world of web programming six years back or so. I would like to revive my knowledge out of pure fun and try out some new technologies. What would make a good development environemnt & combination of CSS and javascript templates? Canvas is popular these days instead of wrapping everything in tables, etc. What is a good and free HTML5 designer? I will not handcode html, nor CSS.

I am NOT interessted in specific serverside environments. I know about Django, wordpress, etc. but I would like to focus on the client side and websocket programming.

Comment: You can't do the *really* fancy stuff without worrying about the server.

Comment: Just FYI the `<canvas>` element has nothing at all to do with page layout. It's like an `<img>` element you can programmatically modify.

Comment: Also lol "I will not handcode html, nor CSS" - how do you expect to "revive your knowledge" if you don't actually code the stuff you want to learn about?  Personally I would not trust **any** IDE to generate HTML or CSS for me, in most cases.

Comment: @Pointy: as much as a table has nthg. to do with page layout, which prevented nobody to abuse it for such.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - I know about that, especially as it would facilitate a lot. But I feel i learn more about how things fit together if I do care about injecting javascript at the right place instead of the environment.

Comment: WebSocket is still fairly new and not in wide use yet. This requires a server that undertands the protocol and a browser with the feature enabled.

Comment: @Mark Renouf: That's why I am not interested in a server framework. For the popular ones the whole topic is like a moving target and implementations are likely to evolve and change. On the client side though the situation is more "at the bare metal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Sencha.  It is a very popular client side framework that you can use to construct real RIAs.

You can also try Sproutcore, which is a JS framework that might appeal to a server side developer because of the pure MVC nature of the framework.  There is an example app on the blog that is linked in my profile.

Comment: Time to brush up my sudoku knowledge as well;) Both tips are very helpful.

Comment: @JohnDoe, pretty awesome eh?  Sproutcore rocks.

Answer (score 2):

- I would say [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) is a must learn, and it's really a lot of fun too.
- I would also look into the suite of [Google APIs](http://code.google.com/more/).  You can do a lot of interesting client side stuff. (For some of the mash-ups you'll need to do some server side programming though).

Comment: How is it different eg. from Dojo?

Comment: I haven't used Dojo, but I suspect they are very similar.  I think JQuery is more popular, so there may be more out there to use and learn from.